# Trigger to insert the name of an employee who badge in after 9am into a custom object late_report__c from work_clocked__c is not working

Tags: apex, trigger

I am new to Salesforce. I have created two custom objects work_clocked__c and late_report__c. If an employee badge in after 9am in work_clocked__c, the employee name must be inserted into late_report__c through trigger written in work_clocked__c. But the trigger action is not working. The same code in execution window appears to be successful. Kindly help me to correct it.

```
trigger late_report_gen on Work_Clocked__c (After Insert, After Update) {
    list<Work_Clocked__c> late=new list<Work_Clocked__c>();
    list<late_report__c>late_report=new list<late_report__c>();
    late=[select name from Work_Clocked__c where Badge_In_Time__c >: time.newinstance(9,0,0,0)];
    for(Work_Clocked__c a:late){
        late_report__c lr= new late_report__c(name=a.name);
        late_report.add(lr);
    }
    insert late_report;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104431/discussion-on-question-by-user78944-trigger-to-insert-the-name-of-an-employee-wh).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of performing a SOQL on Work_Clocked__c object you should use the Trigger context variable ie. `Trigger.new` which provides a list of records that made the trigger fire;
Then iterate on the new List of Work_Clocked__c records to perform your logic.

Also what you shouldn't be doing is writing your logic inside the Trigger rather you should have a separate apex class as a trigger handler where you write all your logic.

```
trigger late_report_gen on Work_Clocked__c (After Insert, After Update) {
    list<Work_Clocked__c> late = new list<Work_Clocked__c>();
    list<late_report__c> late_report = new list<late_report__c>();

    for(Work_Clocked__c objWorkClocked : Trigger.New){

        if(objWorkClocked.Badge_In_Time__c > Time.newInstance(9,0,0,0)){
            late_report__c lr= new late_report__c(name = objWorkClocked.Name);
            late_report.add(lr);        
        }

    }
    insert late_report;
}
```

Comment: Also, I am a little concerned about the field type of Badge_In_Time__c, the comparison
`objWorkClocked.Badge_In_Time__c > Time.newInstance(9,0,0,0)` might fail. If you can provide more detail about the field type of Badge_In_Time__c.

Comment: Thank you!! I'll make the changes